# lastInsertId get from different function

Tags: php, oop, pdo, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I have a form, wich sends information to the database (When filled in)

Form function:

```
function train_add() {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO train_information "
        . "(train_id, image, train_name, tare_weight, number_of_bogies, number_of_axles, wheel_diameter_min, wheel_diameter_max)"
        . "VALUES (train_id, :image, :train_name, :tare_weight, :number_of_bogies, :number_of_axles, :wheel_diameter_min, :wheel_diameter_max) ";
            $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
            $sth->bindParam(':image', $_POST['image'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sth->bindParam(':train_name', $_POST['train_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sth->bindParam(':tare_weight', $_POST['tare_weight'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sth->bindParam(':number_of_bogies', $_POST['number_of_bogies'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sth->bindParam(':number_of_axles', $_POST['number_of_axles'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sth->bindParam(':wheel_diameter_min', $_POST['wheel_diameter_min'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sth->bindParam(':wheel_diameter_max', $_POST['wheel_diameter_max'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sth->execute();
            return $this->pdo->lastInsertId('train_id');
    }
```

Right. So when the form is filled in, it is send to the database (works).

The user will be redirected in 10 seconds (Did this for myself to see if any errors come up).

```
<?php
        //Train information is send to the database, and selects the ID of the just added train//
        $add_train = $database->train_add();
    ?>

    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="10;url=http://localhost:8080/show_axle_table.php?train_id="<?php ['$id'] ?> >
```

show_axle_table.php:

```
<?php
    $show_axle = $database->axles();
?>
    <div id="train_select_table">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Train id</th>
                <th>Number of bogies</th>
                <th>Number of axles</th>
            </tr>
        <div id="loopRow">
            <?php      
                foreach($show_axle as $res){
                //Loop trough results, generate a tablerow every time
            ?>
            <tr>        
                <?php
                echo "<td>" . $res['train_id'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $res['number_of_bogies'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $res['number_of_axles'] . "</td>";
                ?>
            </tr>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
        </div>
        </table>
        </div>
```

And the function:

```
function axles(){
        $id2 = $this->train_add($id);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM train_information WHERE train_id = '$id2'";
        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $sth->bindParam(":id2", $_GET["train_id"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->execute();
        return $sth->fetchAll();
    }
```

Now the table shows me a ID of a train. But it adds 1 so everything else is empty.
For example:
User fills in form. Sends it to Database (train_add) It gets and id of 1 and is done.

Then the page redirects to the show_axle_table.php. Function should get the last inserted id. but it shows me a ID of 2.

Also i want the ID to be shown in the top of my page like:

```
show_axle_table.php?train_id="<?php ['$id'] ?>
```

But right now it shows nothing. (train_id=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update like this:

```
<?php
        //Train information is send to the database, and selects the ID of the just added train//
        if (!(isset($_GET['train_id]) && $_GET['train_id'])) {
            $add_train = $database->train_add();
        }
    ?>

    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="10;url=http://localhost:8080/show_axle_table.php?train_id="<?php echo $add_train; ?> >



<?php
    $show_axle = $database->axles($_GET['train_id']);
?>
    <div id="train_select_table">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Train id</th>
                <th>Number of bogies</th>
                <th>Number of axles</th>
            </tr>
        <div id="loopRow">
            <?php      
                foreach($show_axle as $res){
                //Loop trough results, generate a tablerow every time
            ?>
            <tr>        
                <?php
                echo "<td>" . $res['train_id'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $res['number_of_bogies'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $res['number_of_axles'] . "</td>";
                ?>
            </tr>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
        </div>
        </table>
        </div>
```

And function as

```
function axles($id){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM train_information WHERE train_id = '$id'";
        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $sth->bindParam(":id2", $_GET["train_id"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->execute();
        return $sth->fetchAll();
    }
```

Comment: it work exaclty the same. Also i forgot to tell it has a error: Notice: Undefined variable: id in ..\db_login.php on line 89 Wich is the "function axles"

Comment: Edited the answer. Have a look.

Comment: The error is gone now, and it show a ID. But still is adds +1 to the id. So i have filled in the form like a a a a a. and the ID is 189. Then when it redirects and shows me the id. it shows ID: 190, and the rest is NULL. So it does the insert statement again. but then without information

Comment: Also when i refresh the page where i see the table. It keeps adding 1 to the ID.

Comment: Check now. Edited the answer

Comment: Still same results :( But i did this: <?php
        //Train information is send to the database, and selects the ID of the just added train//
        $add_train = $database->train_add();
    ?>
    <a href="http://localhost:8080/show_axle_table.php?train_id=<?php echo $add_train; ?>">klik hier ff</a>
    <!--<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="10;url=http://localhost:8080/show_axle_table.php?train_id="<?php echo $add_train; ?> >--> (So i made a a href instead of a auto redirect). And now when i click it it shows me the correct ID in the top. But still adds +1 in table and DB

Comment: I don't know your problem exactly. Anyway add the below line as the first line of the function: train_add():

if (empty($_POST))  {
return;
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74707/discussion-between-mitch-and-sanjay-kumar-n-s).